# Lambda in GO and Aurora MySQL Serverless 2

Tags: go, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

You could modify the minimum ACUS of your clusters by means of a lambda.

Now I can't do it, it gives me a parameter error but I'm still using V2 of the GO SDK

Is there any possibility to modify from a GO lambda the minimum ACUS in Aurora MySQL Serverless 2?

Regards

Pablo Tilotta